# (Windows) Dynamic base image not changing base

Tags: windows, windows-10, aslr

I have built a CMake console app with Visual Studio 2019 Community, with DynamicBase enabled. The first thing this app does is prints out the address of main(). I have tried the same with a ConsoleProject (not CMake), as well as 32 and 64 bit versions.

The address of main() never changes.

I have verified using PEView and ProcessExplorer that the image has ASLR enabled.

Is there something obvious I am missing?

OS: Win10 (up to date); VS latest download.

Comment: Reboot the machine.

Comment: Ugh. I'm too used to Linux where it changes each time. Is there any other way to reset it?

Answer (score 0):

As per comment from @Hans Passant above, these addresses only reset on reboot on Windows 10 (it seems).

This link:

https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2020/03/six-facts-about-address-space-layout-randomization-on-windows.html

Also discusses the reuse of base addresses.